# Type of Circular Pattern for camera calibration

Tags: opencv

I would like to calibrate a camera using a circular pattern.Can i use this kind of pattern for this task?
I tried to detect the circles using blob detection from opencv and tuned different parameters in it.Unfortunately ,it is not able to detect the circles.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1bkQ9e4xYBSWRWlh57-yC7O8h6o5GPjPR

Comment: Link for the Image:

Comment: Circular patterns are fine, but the issue with the image you provided is that the contrast is not very good/sharp. You probably need some pre-processing/tresholding before passing the image to the detector

Comment: It would be helpful if you could tag the programming language you are using.

Answer (score 0):

Try Hough Circles from scikit-image: https://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/auto_examples/edges/plot_circular_elliptical_hough_transform.html

Comment: I am actually using this circular pattern to calibrate camera in MATLAB.Since these is not much gradiant change from the holes in that image ,I could able to solve the problem by filling them with white paint and using cv.Blobdetetctor i could able to detect those point.Thanks a lot for the suggestion